# How can I fill empty rows with google sheets query (group by month)?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm building dashboard where data is grouped by month based on dates in column `A` (pls note output transposes the columns => rows) :

```
=TRANSPOSE( QUERY(Data;"select sum(F) * -1 where D contains 'Foo' or D contains 'Bar' group by month(A) label sum(F) * -1 'Foo & bar'"))
```

However, as one of the months has no rows the code will skip the month:

Assume we have data a,b,d from months 1,2,4 (month 3 has no data) so output looks like this:

1 | 2 | 3 | 4

a | b | d | _

but it should look like this:

1 | 2 | 3 | 4

a | b | _  | d |

**Any ideas how can I generate the empty row?**

Answer (score 0):

I'd insert a row in the data for month 3 and `Foo` in ColumnD.

Add it via a separate table then:

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY({Data;Table};"select sum(Col6) * -1 where Col4 contains 'Foo' or Col4 contains 'Bar' group by month(Col1) label sum(Col6) * -1 'Foo & bar'"))
```

Comment: Unfortunately data is generated elsewhere and I cannot add anything there. In addition, if I add something there it will mess the data... :)